# Select option dinâmico

Tags: javascript

Tenho um `input:text` com `datepicker`.

Selecionando a data, ela é enviada via ajax e retornado os valores em Json.
Tudo certo até ai, funciona perfeitamente aqui no desktop usando o chrome.

Porém no iphone que é o mais importante esses resultados não são alterados dinamicamente no `select option`.

Segue o código usado:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="data"]').datepicker({
        startDate: '<?php echo date('d-m-Y'); ?>',
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
        language: 'pt-BR',
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
    }).on('change', function(){

        var select_element = document.getElementById('hora');
        select_element.innerHTML = "";
        /// Exemplo simples do resultado em Json.
        var data = {'0':'22:00','1':'22:30','2':'23:00','3':'23:30'};
            $.each(data, function(key, valor) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = valor;
                opt.innerHTML = valor;
                select_element.appendChild(opt);
            });
        $('.datepicker').hide();

    });
});
```

Comment: Você está usando [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: Podes montar um jsFiddle que reproduza o problema para podermos testar no móvel?